# Putting restrictions on button

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my program an area called 'validDrop' is highlighted for the user to drag and drop items into.

A new area is highlighted when the button, 'minibutton' is clicked.

I want to tell the program to only allow the button to be clicked if the current area (validDrop) is styled by 'wordglow2' and 'wordglow4'.

I have tried this, Why won't it work?

```
if ($(validDrop).hasClass('wordglow2', 'wordglow4')) {
    $('.minibutton').click(true);
} else {
    $('.minibutton').click(false);
}
```

Comment: is minibutton actually a <button> tag?

Comment: Did you look at the [`.hasClass()` doco](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) - it only takes one parameter. Did you look at the [`.click()` doco](http://api.jquery.com/click/) - it doesn't take a boolean as a parameter...

Comment: Yes its a input type='button'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `hasClass` doesn't take more than one parameter, and because `.click` either triggers a click or binds a click listener, it doesn't set clickability.

Depending on what `.minibutton` is, you could do something like:

```
var valid = $(validDrop).hasClass('wordglow2') && $(validDrop).hasClass('wordglow4')
$('.minibutton').prop('disabled', !valid);
```

If it's not a type that can be disabled, you might consider something like this:

```
$('.minibutton').toggleClass('disabled', !valid);
```

And bind the click listener like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.minibutton:not(.disabled)', function() {
    // click action here
});
```

As ThiefMaster points out in comments, `$(validDrop).is('.wordglow2.wordglow4')` is a functionally equivalent way of checking that the drop has both classes.

Comment: @sMilbz: I don't get the code you've posted. The `$(validDrop).hasClass` stuff is inside the button click listener? When the click has already happened? What do you want to happen? Waht do you expect `$('.minibutton').click(true)` to do?

Comment: Where would you put your answer in my code if we took that bit out? @David hedlund

Comment: @sMilbz: I don't know exactly how you want the code to work, but the first two lines should go wherever in your code you want to enable or disable the `.minibutton`. That should be all you need since `.minibutton` is an `input` and thus can be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can alsou use `.bind()` and `.unbind()` to add and remove click event to your button as in my example http://jsfiddle.net/Uz6Ej/